# C# MVC Entity Framework, child ID, grandchild ID is unnecessarily incrementing when DataContext.SaveChanges() is called

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple design of 3 classes in C# entity framework:

```
class Foo{ int id, string name}
class ParentFoo{ int id, Foo foo}
class GrandparentFoo{int id, ParentFoo parentFoo}
```

When I try to save records in GrandparentFoo using DataContext.SaveChanges(), the ids of ParentFoo and Foo are incremented which is not expected.

```
function AddGrandparent(int g_id, ParentFoo pf){

 using (var dc = dcHelper_.CreateDataContext())
        {
            result = dc.GrandparentFoos.Add(new GrandparentFoo()
            {
                id = g_id,
                parentFoo = pf 
            });

            dc.SaveChanges(); }}
```

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: I tried debugging the function, the values till dc.SaveChanges() are correct. As soon as the dc.SaveChanges() line is executed the ids are incremented which is not desirable.

Comment: Hiw do you create parent foo outside function?

Comment: Its not related to this still a thought.
Why do you need to set `id = 1` here in Grandparentfoo is it suppose to increment automatically when identity specification is On in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParentFoo etc. are not associated to your context so that context will treat them as new entities. Avoid passing entities around outside of the context they are loaded to avoid issues like this. Instead, if you load the Parent/child data needed with IDs into POCO view models then retrieve references as needed, you can avoid problems with unassociated entities.

Using your code:

```
void AddGrandparent(int id, ParentFoo pf)
{
  using (var dc = dcHelper_.CreateDataContext())
  {
    var parent = dc.ParentFoos.Find(pf.Id);
    dc.GrandparentFoos.Add(new GrandparentFoo
    {
      Id = id,
      ParentFoo = parent 
    });
    dc.SaveChanges(); 
  }
}
```

If GrandParentFoo has identity set, you can do away with setting IDs, EF will ignore it when added to the context. If parent contains a reference to grandparent, then you may need to set that reference in ParentFoo as well.

```
var grandParent = dc.GrandparentFoos.Add(new GrandparentFoo
{
  Id = id,
  ParentFoo = parent 
});
parent.GrandparentFoo = grandParent;
```

Edit:
If GrandParent has a collection of Parent and you want to create a Grandparent and associate it to one existing Parent:

First, be sure that the Parents collection in GrandParent is initialized to a new List/HashSet

```
public virtual ICollection<ParentFoo> ParentFoos {get; set;} = new List<Parent>();
```

then

```
 using (var dc = dcHelper_.CreateDataContext())
 {
   var parent = dc.ParentFoos.Find(pf.Id);
   var grandParent = dc.GrandparentFoos.Add(new GrandparentFoo
   {
     Id = id
   });
   grandParent.ParentFoos.Add(parent);
   parent.GrandparentFoo = grandParent;
 }
```

The children of ParentFoo don't matter given the parent and it's associated children already exist in the data.

Comment: How do I achieve this if the class GrandparentFoo has attribute of ICollection<ParentFoo> and Parent has ICollection<Foo>?

Comment: I've expanded the answer to cover the collection scenario.